# Runtime vs Syntax vs Logic Errors for Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to identify a few errors in this code below and write which kind of error it is and replace it with the correct code. I've found the three but I have a question on differentiating whether one is a runtime or a logic error.

```
def mirror(word):                         #  1
    result == ''                          #  2
    ord_a = ord('a')                      #  3
    ord_z = ord('z')                      #  4
    for c in word[:-1]:                   #  5
        value = ord('c') - ord_a          #  6
        new_value = ord_z - value         #  7
        result += chr(new_value)          #  8
        return result                     #  9
```

I've successfully identified 4 lines (line 2, line 5, line 6, line 9) and made adjustments (testing various inputs work in the new function) here:

```
def mirror(word):                         #  1
    result = ''                           #  2 ##### runtime error* or logic?
    ord_a = ord('a')                      #  3
    ord_z = ord('z')                      #  4
    for c in word[::-1]:                  #  5 ##### logic error (supposed to reverse slicing)
        value = ord(c) - ord_a            #  6 ##### logic error (ord(c) not ord('c'))
        new_value = ord_z - value         #  7
        result += chr(new_value)          #  8 
    return result                         #  9 ###### syntax error (wrong indent)
```

My question is would line 2 count as a runtime error or a logic error, given that in the erroneous code it was comparing equality "==" rather than referencing an assignment with "=" .

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

The errors can be best delineated as follows:

- A syntax error is something caught by the compiler/interpreter and it's incorrect use of the language itself. For example, `for:`, which is invalid Python.
- A runtime error is a problem that cannot be detected before the code runs but causes an issue that *is* caught during the program run. An example would be `x = open("nosuchfile.txt")` because the file is checked for existence only at runtime.
- A logic error is something that *isn't* caught, either at compile or runtime but which causes an issue. An example would be working out the sum of all numbers from one to `n` inclusive with `the_sum = sum([x for x in range(n)]` - that wouldn't include the `n` in the sum.

If you actually *call* the function with something like:

```
print("running")
mirror("hello")
```

you will see there are no syntax errors because it successfully starts running.

Using the definitions above:

- `result == ''` is a runtime error, it detects that you are trying to compare the uninitialised `result` with something (a `result = 7` before that makes the error go away).
- Everything else is a logic error since it neither prevents compilation nor stops it running because of an unrecoverable fault.